# Balanced brackets in regexp

Tags: regex, string, matlab

How can I find maximum possible pattern in a string in Matlab, which matches some expression. Example will clarify what I mean:

```
str = 'tan(sin*cos)';
str = 'tan(sin(exp)*cos(exp))';
```

I want to find the patterns, which look like `tan(\w*)`. But I want brackets in `tan` to be balanced. Is there any approach to do it?

Comment: Normally I would use a recursive regex `(?R)`, but there is no mention of that in the Matlab documentation. Would it be possible for you to use a simple loop to count the parentheses, instead of using a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible without recusrsive regular expressions. For example, this string:

```
str = 'tan(tan(tan(x) + 4) + cos(x))'
```

would have to be regex'ed "from the inside out", something only recursion can do.

Instead, I'd just use a more practical solution:

```
regexprep(str, 'tan', '')
```

and/or split further when necessary. Or, as Ruud already suggested, just use a loop:

```
str{1} = 'tan(x)';
str{2} = 'tan(sin(exp)*cos(exp)) + tan(tan(x) + 4)';

S = regexp(str, 'tan\(');
match = cell(size(str));
[match{:}] = deal({});
for ii = 1:numel(str)
    if ~isempty(S{ii})
        for jj = 1:numel(S{ii})

            open  = false;
            start = S{ii}(jj)+4;
            for kk = start : numel(str{ii})            
                switch str{ii}(kk)
                    case '('
                        open = true;
                    case ')'
                        if open
                            open = false;
                        else
                            match{ii}{end+1} = str{ii}(start:kk-1);
                            break;
                        end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```